# Non-inline function from another source file takes precedence over inline function

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

I was experimenting with inline functions in different translation units and stumbled upon this interesting example.

```
// A.cpp
#include <iostream>

void f() {
    std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

inline void f() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and link the 2 files with `g++ main.cpp A.cpp` and run the executable, "Bye" is printed to console. Why is it "Bye" that gets printed and not "Hello", and how why does this not violate One-Definition Rule?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does violate One Definition Rule and what you see is one of the things that ODR violations can do.

Comment: Yes it's an ODR violation and causes undefined behavior, i.e. anything can happen. From [cppreference - Definitions and ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition): "_The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined_".

Comment: Nothing in the code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.